# Resized image pixelation in IE9

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

On an internal web page managed by a business user, an image is often uploaded that is much larger than the size of the display area.  The image is rendered to fit, but looks much better in IE8 than in IE9.

Below are screenshots captured to show the difference.  As my example is an image for internal use I have cropped to only show a portion.  It is however enough to see the IE9 rendering is much worse than the IE8 rendering.

IE8:  [image: cropped image as viewed in IE8]

IE9:  [image: cropped image as viewed in IE9]

So, the question in two parts.

> What is the underlying difference in how the browsers render images?
>
> Is there anything that can be done to 'fix' IE9's rendering (css or browser setting perhaps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE often changed resampling algorithms and in IE9 too. Not tested bug I hope [**this**](http://www.lilianagaete.com/ie-image-scaling-bug/) could help you.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't have that project in front of me anymore, but I will test as soon as I can.